# How to ignore a cell when the value passed is empty or null

Tags: smartsheet-api

I have an integration that’s using the Smartsheet SDK, and the SmartSheet has a few fields which are dates and numbers, along with several other freeform (for lack of a better word) string fields.  The problem I’m having is that the date fields don’t seem to be  able to be ignored, i.e., I get an error message if I don’t supply an actual date or number.

Here’s the code I’m using:

```
            Cell[] cells = new Cell[]
                                {
            //other string rows here that aren't causing problems...
            ....

            //Start of rows that cause problems
                                    ,new Cell.AddCellBuilder(columnMap["Actual Hours"], GIMap["xTACProjectTask.actualHours"]).Build()
                                    ,new Cell.AddCellBuilder(columnMap["Pct Complete"], pctComplete).SetStrict(false).Build()  //projectTaskGIData[i][13].Trim()).Build()
                                    ,new Cell.AddCellBuilder(columnMap["Days From Close"], GIMap["xTACProjectTask.daysFromClose"]).Build()
                                    ,new Cell.AddCellBuilder(columnMap["Due Date"], dueDate).SetStrict(false).Build()
                                    ,new Cell.AddCellBuilder(columnMap["Start Date"], startDate).SetStrict(false).Build()
                                    ,new Cell.AddCellBuilder(columnMap["End Date"], endDate).SetStrict(false).Build()
                                    ,new Cell.AddCellBuilder(columnMap["Related Link"], GIMap["xTACProjectTask.relatedLink"] + "").Build()
                                };
                    Row rowA = new Row.AddRowBuilder(null, true, null, null, null).SetCells(cells).Build();
                    smartsheet.SheetResources.RowResources.AddRows(_SheetID, new Row[] { rowA });
```

Is there a syntax for the new cell row that specifies if it’s empty or null to ignore that cell?

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest that you try using Fiddler (or a similar tool) to inspect the `value` that's being specified for Date cells that you want to be *ignored* and see what value's actually being set for those cells. If you can get your code to set those cell values to either `null` or an empty string (`""`) then you shouldn't receive the type of error you're describing.

I've verified this approach using Postman (i.e., specifying the raw API requests directly instead of using an SDK). Using Postman, I'm able to specify either an empty string (`""`) or the value `null` as the `value` of a Date column in an **Add Rows** request, and the new row is successfully added to the sheet (with an empty/blank Date column). i.e., both of the following requests are successful.

**Specify empty string for Date column:**

```
POST https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/3932034054809476/rows

[
    {
        "cells": [
            ...
            {
                "columnId": 3849953725441924,
                "value": ""
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**Specify `null` for Date column:**

```
POST https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/3932034054809476/rows

[
    {
        "cells": [
            ...
            {
                "columnId": 3849953725441924,
                "value": null
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Alternatively, if you're trying to set the value of a cell in a Date column (where "restrict to only Dates" is specified for the column properties in the Smartsheet UI) to a non-empty, non-date string value -- then you might try setting the `overrideValidation` property to `true` for that cell in your **Add Row** requests. (*Note*: You must be a sheet Admin to use this property.)